# Getting an error that images is null while trying to show a preview of the uploaded images in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, foreach, rxjs

I have this function to upload multiple images and it works, now I need to show preview of all the images the user has selected. I tried using `map` and `forEach` to try to loop through and show the images but it isn't working. `console.log(images)` is showing the url of uploaded images, but `images.map()` or `images.ForEach` is throwing a null error. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this? I am new to react, so need some help.

This is the code:

```
const fileObj = [];
const imageArray = [];
const [images, setImages] = useState(null); 

const uploadMultipleFiles = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === 'images') {
        fileObj.push(e.target.files)
        for (let i = 0; i < fileObj[0].length; i++) {
            imageArray.push(URL.createObjectURL(fileObj[0][i]))
            // console.log(imageArray)
        }
        setImages({ images: imageArray })
    }
}

{console.log(images)}
<div className="form-group multi-preview">
  { {(imageArray || []).map(url => (
         <img src={url} alt="" />
      ))} 
  }
</div>
                    
 <label htmlFor="images">
      <input
         accept="image/*"
         className={classes.input}
         id="images"
         onChange={uploadMultipleFiles}
         name="images"
         type="file"
         multiple
         ref={register({required:true})}
     />
     Images
     <IconButton color="primary" component="span">
         <PhotoCamera style={{fontSize:"xx-large"}} />
     </IconButton>
  </label>
```

Comment: where is a `setImages` defined?

Comment: Hey, I have it defined as this
`const [images, setImages] = useState(null); `

Comment: It should have been also in the code. I guess there is the problem.

Comment: Oh..Okay, Thanks for letting me know. I will update the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your `setImages({ images: imageArray })` call, you'll get value of `images` const to be:

```
images = {images: [...]} // [...] is the imageArray
```

so you'll have to access it as `images.images`, or rather set it as `setImages(imageArray)` which will be accessible as you expect.

Also, access the state variable and use `map` instead of `forEach`, not the `imageArray`. So instead of `imageArray.forEach(...)` use `images.map(...)`. Map returns an array with values returned from the function calls. Whereas `forEach` returns undefined.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, I will check it  and get back to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{imageArray.length>0 ? 
<div>
  {imageArray.map((element)=>{
  return(
    <img src={element} alt="" />
    )
  })}
</div>
:null}
```

Hope this solves

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. But still the image is not getting displayed.

Comment: can you share a sc of imageArray in the location that we are trying to map?

Comment: Actually i'm trying to show the images after selecting the files  using this function `uploadMultipleFiles `  and then in the process appending the array `imageArray` and then showing the images from that array. so I guess imageArray is the source. Hope that's what you aksed.